# Python timer on randint

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

If I have this code:

```
r = randint(0, 255)
g = randint(0, 255)
b = randint(0, 255)
screen.fill((r, g, b))
```

How do I set it so that it chooses a random number every, say, 10 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **many different** approaches for that problem. :)

A very simple and quick and dirty method is to **pause the game** (i.e. set a delay) in the main game loop for an amount of time. You could use PyGames [`pygame.time.delay()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.delay) function:

```
#import pygame and randint function from random module
import pygame
from random import randint

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800)) #create screen

while True:
    #get events from the event queue
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()

    #create random variables r, g and b
    r = randint(0, 255)
    g = randint(0, 255)
    b = randint(0, 255)

    #fill screen
    screen.fill((r, g, b))

    #update whole screen
    pygame.display.flip()

    #set timout for 500ms (i.e. pause game for 500ms)
    pygame.time.delay(500)
```

The problem with this approach is, that you **can´t get any events** and do some stuff **for the amount of time (e.g. 500ms) the game pauses**.

To avoid this problem you could **create** your very **own event which appears on the event queue every given number of milliseconds**. You could use [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) to create an event:

```
import pygame
from random import randint

pygame.init()

#create a new event id called event_500ms
event_500ms = pygame.USEREVENT + 1

#set timer event to appear on the event queue every 500 number of milliseconds
pygame.time.set_timer(event_500ms, 500)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))

while True:
    #get events from the event queue
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()

        #check for event_500ms event
        if ev.type == event_500ms:

            r = randint(0, 255)
            g = randint(0, 255)
            b = randint(0, 255)

            screen.fill((r, g, b))

            pygame.display.flip()
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: @YuBinLee: No porblem, I'm glad I could help :)